# Is this proper usage of IReferenceResolver inside a JsonConverter?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm using JSON.NET to deserialize JSON (which I don't control) that represents an `Event` of a specific type with inner `data`:

```
{
  "id": "abc",
  "type": "a",
  "data": {
    // Data specific to "type"="a".
    "a": 1
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "id": "def",
  "type": "b",
  "data": {
    // Data specific to "type"="b".
    "b": 1
  }
}
```

This JSON should be deserialized to the following classes:

```
public class Event
{
    public string Id { get; }
    public string Type { get; }
    public EventDataBase Data { get; }

    public Event(string id, string type, EventDataBase data)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Data = data;
    }
}

public abstract class EventDataBase
{

}

public class AEventData : EventDataBase
{
    public string A { get; }

    public AEventData(string a)
    {
        this.A = a;
    }
}

public class BEventData : EventDataBase
{
    public string B { get; }

    public BEventData(string b)
    {
        this.B = b;
    }
}
```

The correct inherited class of `EventDataBase` should be instantiated when deserializing the `Event`.

There are many solutions to this problem, but they usually involve having the `type` belong on the `data`, not the parent. And if it does belong on the parent, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22539730) is to usually convert the JSON for `Event` as a `JObject` and then *manually* deserialize it. While this is possible, it feels like a hack to leverage only *part* of JSON.NET to do the deserialization.

The solution I've come up uses `IReferenceResolver` to add a reference to the `type`, and then when attempting to deserialize the `data`, get the reference to the parent type, and use it to determine the concrete class that needs to be deserialized:

```
public class CustomContractResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (member.DeclaringType == typeof(Event) && member.Name == nameof(Event.Type))
        {
            property.Order = Int32.MinValue;
            property.MemberConverter = new EventTypeConverter();
        }
        else if (member.DeclaringType == typeof(Event) && member.Name == nameof(Event.Data))
        {
            property.Order = Int32.MaxValue;
            property.MemberConverter = new EventDataConverter();
        }

        return property;
    }

    private class EventTypeConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanWrite => false;

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(string);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var eventType = reader.Value as string;
            serializer.ReferenceResolver.AddReference(serializer, "parentEvent.type", eventType);
            return eventType;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    private class EventDataConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanWrite => false;

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(EventDataBase);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var eventType = serializer.ReferenceResolver.ResolveReference(serializer, "parentEvent.type") as string;

            var eventDataType = GetEventDataTypeFromEventType(eventType);

            return serializer.Deserialize(reader, eventDataType);
        }

        private static Type GetEventDataTypeFromEventType(string eventType)
        {
            switch (eventType?.ToLower())
            {
                case "a":
                    return typeof(AEventData);
                case "b":
                    return typeof(BEventData);
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's a .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mZkMcu) sample of this in action.

Is this valid use of the `IReferenceResolver`? Does JSON.NET clear the reference resolver during each call deserialize (so that multiple calls don't store the old reference)? Is it thread-safe?

Comment: One problem is that, if your JSON contains more than one `Event`, deserialization will fail due to an attempt to add duplicate keys to the reference resolver table.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/VULtfu for a demo.  A second problem is that a [JSON object](http://www.json.org/) is defined by the standard to be *an unordered set of name/value pairs* so you really shouldn't be assuming the `"type"` property comes before the `"data"` property.

Comment: @dbc The good news is that the JSON we receive will not be in the format that I presented. So it will be impossible to have multiple events per JSON payload. Also, after posting this question, I too realized that the `type` property can come *after* the `data` property. I switched to doing a double-parse (similar to JSON.NET's metadata handling) to determine the "type" ahead of time. However, I still need to pass the "type" around to the "data" property's convert so I'm still using the solution I posted here.

Comment: I can't edit my last comment but I meant "...the JSON we receive will *only* be in the format that I presented".